# Engrave on M-Disc

Tags: burning, blu-ray, optical-media

I want to use 100GB M-Disc for Backup.  How can one determine whether the M-Disc Writing was engraved properly and successfully on the non-volatile substance?  I plan to use Brasero for writing.

What does one have to do, burn with brasero and everything is figured out automatically when you insert an M-Disc?  I have just got a Pioneer BDR-XS07S Blu-Ray Burner.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Answer (score 0):

I use Windows CyberLink Power2Go version 11 software specifically for M-Discs.

I do care much about my backups, and while the humidity here is high relatively speaking, I *must* use M-Discs.

But to your case, I found evidence of an advanced feature called:

> **Defect Management** in my Power2Go 11

This naming, however, can differ greatly program from another program.

I don't know if any Linux product is able to do the same *damage protection* or how to call it generically.

[This Dell page](https://www.dell.com/support/kbdoc/en-us/000148087/cyberlink-media-suite-frequently-asked-questions?lwp=rt) notes some more info on this *checkbox*:

> Select **Enable defect management** to have CyberLink Power2Go try to fix any defects on a disc so that content burns correctly.

---

I also made a screenshot for you of this aspect of BluRay burning, seemingly generic, I assume not only applicable to M-Discs:

Click to enlarge the image:

[image: Enable defect management in CyberLink Power2Go 11]

---

I hope this info helps a bit. Cheers.

Comment: It could help, although the real test is information specific to unix-like system.

Comment: @Dilna Maybe you will be able to find future references to this feature in Linux programs.